# SIFR: Surface tooltips off words inside SIFR'd text

Tags: sifr, inline, tooltip

If I SIFR-ize the following text:

"We make <span>blankets </span> and pillows for giraffes."

I know that I can make the SPAN part a different color, and I can even assign it a :hover color change in CSS. But can I target that SPAN for a Javascript tooltip as I would if the text wasn't SIFR'd?

Answer (score 1):

No. You can get callbacks when the mouse goes over the entire Flash movie, but not for specific elements within the movie.